# fetching value from html select to jQuery to change css class

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, addclass

I have a select option in my modal as seen below:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <select class="style" name="style" form="styleform">
    <option value="Sky">Sky</option>
    <option value="Boulder">Boulder</option>
    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
    <option value="Forest">Forest</option></option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Each of the options in select should be linked to a style in css. Namely style1, style2, style3 and style4.

I tried this code to add the style to my panel but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if($(".style").val()=="sky"){
  $('.panel').addClass("style1");
}
```

I also tried removing the existing/default class of the panel but that also didn't work.

Comment: Maybe `$(".style").val()=="sky"` should be `$(".style").val()=="Sky"` or `$(".style").val().toLowerCase()=="sky"`

Comment: oopps sorry, that was totally simple wasn't it? :3 thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your code to any event so this code will never be executed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.style').change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Sky"){
            $('.panel').addClass("style1");
        }
    });
});
```

the document `.ready` is to wait till the dom is ready and the `.change` is to listen to the user that changes the option

Note that your code is case sensitive so in your original code your if will never evaluate to true since "sky" is different from "Sky"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was the modal that was hindering the processes in jQuery...

what I did was just took the html select out of the modal and place it onto the panel heading

```
<div class="panel-heading">To do List                 
  <select class="pull-right" id="style" name="style">
    <option value="Sky">Sky</option>
    <option value="Boulder">Boulder</option>
    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
    <option value="Forest">Forest</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

then I used this code in jQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if($("#style option:selected" ).text()=="Sky"){
  $('.panel').removeClass("style2");
    $('.panel').removeClass("style3");
    $('.panel').removeClass("style4");
    $('.panel').addClass("style1");
  }
})
```

and so on to change the styles